# AWS RedShift to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aws

Estoy programando una lambda para que se conecte a una base de datos de RedShift, ejecute una query y guarde el resultado de esta en un dataframe de pandas. He probado varias alternativas y no soy capaz. Estoy utilizando la librería  de python psycopg2 así que una vez creo la conexión, procedo a ejecutar la query y cargarla como df:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname=REDSHIFT_DBNAME,
        host=REDSHIFT_HOST,
        port=REDSHIFT_PORT,
        user=REDSHIFT_USER,
        password=REDSHIFT_PASSWORD,

c = conn.cursor
query = pd.read_sql_query ('''
    SELECT a, b
    FROM 'table' 
    GROUP BY B
    ''', conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(query, columns = ['a', 'b']
```

Me da error al leer la query:

> {   "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid
> syntax (lambda_function.py, line 19)",   "errorType":
> "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",   "stackTrace": [
> "  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 19\n        query = pd.read_sql_query ('''\n"   ] }

Probando el código editado como sugiere el usuario abulafia:

> ```
> cur = conn.cursor()
> query = pd.read_sql_query ("SELECT a, b FROM 'table' LIMIT 5", conn)
> df = pd.DataFrame(query, columns =['a', 'b']
> ```

Sigue saliendo el siguiente error:

> {   "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid
> syntax (lambda_function.py, line 20)",   "errorType":
> "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",   "stackTrace": [
> "  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 20\n        query = pd.read_sql_query ("SELECT a, b FROM 'table' LIMIT 5", conn)\n"   ] }

No se porque ponga lo que ponga me salen las "/n"

Comment: Quizás no le gusta que la query SQL ocupe varias lineas? Ponlo todo en una sola línea, entre comillas normales.

Comment: He probado y me da el mismo error :( Muchas gracias abulafia por la ayuda aun así

Comment: Mmmm... seguro que te da el mismo error? En el error que has pegado aparecía un \n justo después de pd.read_sql_query("", y supuse que era el retorno de carro tras las comillas de apertura debido a la multilinea. Si ahora esa multilinea no existe ese \n tampoco debería aparecer en el error... De todas formas ese error no parece tampoco un error de python, tiene pinta de ser un json. ¿Cómo lo has obtenido? ¿Donde te sale? ¿Podrías pegar el _stacktrace_ completo?

Comment: He actualizado el primer mensaje añadiendo la query como sugieres y el resultado obtenido. Efectivamente, es el error que muestra la lambda en el entorno de AWS al ejecutarse.

Comment: ¿no será que sobran las comillas alrededor de `'table'`?

Comment: Ya lo conseguí arreglar, ese era uno de los errores justamente. ¡Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una posibilidad, pero, si al final de la query, pones **;**, algo como esto:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
query = pd.read_sql_query ("SELECT a, b FROM 'table' LIMIT 5;", conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(query, columns =['a', 'b']
```

Al final, el **;** en SQL indica el fin de la query.

Comment: ¡Efectivamente hay que añadir el punto y coma al final de todas las querys! Esta arreglado aunque ese no parece ser el fallo y sigue saliendo el problema. Me he asegurado de la conexión y funciona bien, es solo al introducir la query.

Answer (score -1):

Guarda la query en una variable, ahi podes usarla en más de una línea y después pasa esa query al conector para ejecutarla.
Por cierto, a la ultima línea le falta un  parentesis, no sé si es un error en tu código o un error de cuando copiaste el código.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).